# JsonMappingException while parse an enumeration

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I've this class with a constructor marked with `@JsonCreator` for deserialize my JSON string into my class `Meal`:

```
public class Meal {
    private int proteins;
    private int lipids;
    private int carbohydrates;
    private int totalKcal;
    private List<Dish> dishes;
    private int slot;
    private MealEnum mealType;

    @JsonCreator
    public Meal(@JsonProperty("mealType") MealEnum mealType, @JsonProperty("dishes") List<Dish> dishes,
                @JsonProperty("slot") int slot, @JsonProperty("totalKcal") int totalKcal,
                @JsonProperty("carbohydrates") int carbohydrates, @JsonProperty("proteins") int proteins,
                @JsonProperty("lipids") int lipids) {
        this.mealType = mealType;
        this.dishes = dishes;
        this.slot = slot;
        this.totalKcal = totalKcal;
        this.carbohydrates = carbohydrates;
        this.proteins = proteins;
        this.lipids = lipids;
    }
```

I have also this enum with a constructor marked with `@JsonCreator`:

```
public enum MealEnum {
    BREAKFAST(0, "BREAKFAST"),
    LUNCH(1, "LUNCH"),
    SUPPER(2, "SUPPER");
    @JsonIgnore
    private final int intValue;
    private final String stringValue;

    MealEnum(int intValue, String stringValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
        this.stringValue = Objects.requireNonNull(stringValue);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    MealEnum(@JsonProperty("mealType") String stringValue) {
        this.intValue = DynamicDietistUtils.getMealEnumFromMealType(stringValue);
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
    }

    public int getIntValue() {
        return this.intValue;
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return this.stringValue;
    }
}
```

The JSON to deserialize is the following:

```
{
    "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
    "proteins": 60,
    "lipids": 147,
    "carbohydrates": 461,
    "totalKcal": 664,
    "dishes": [{
        "id": 0,
        "description": "burro (10g)",
        "proteins": 0.0,
        "lipids": 72.0,
        "carbohydrates": 0.0,
        "kcal": 76
    }, {
        "id": 0,
        "description": "pane comune (100g)",
        "proteins": 32.0,
        "lipids": 0.0,
        "carbohydrates": 252.0,
        "kcal": 290
    }],
    "slot": 1
}
```

When Jackson try to deserialize the JSON, the following error appears:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of mainpackage.data.model.Meal: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('mealType')
```

Where am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that in java you couldn't call enum constructor from any place except enum values initialization list.
So jackson couldn't use enum constructor, you can create static method instead which will lookup value from string for you.

```
@JsonCreator
public static MealEnum forValue(String value) {
    return MaelEnum.valueOf(value); //or any other way to lookup your enum value for given string
}
```

Comment: @parion have you removed annotation from your constructor? is the error the same?

Comment: Yes, it's the same.

Comment: @pairon which jackson version do you use? also ensure that your creator method is public static (not sure, maybe you can do with package-local/protected as well).

Comment: Jackson 2.* is the version

Answer (score 0):

Change your enum json creator as a factory method

```
@JsonCreator
public static MealEnum fromString(String stringValue) {
    int value = DynamicDietistUtils.getMealEnumFromMealType(stringValue);
    for(MealEnum e : values()) {
        if(value == e.getIntValue()) {
            return e;
        }  
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(stringValue);

}
```

OR (if mealType in json matches with Enum constants)

```
@JsonCreator
public static MealEnum fromString(String stringValue) {

     // for case insensitive use stringValue.toUpperCase()
     return MealEnum.valueOf(stringValue);
}
```

Comment: Yes, mealType matches with enum constants, but the factory method doesn't resolve the error.

Comment: It should work, check your project don't have both jackson 1 & 2.

Comment: I also marked "String stringValue" with @JsonProperty("mealType"). Is this an error?

Comment: JsonProperty / @JsonIgnore don't make sense in enums

Comment: `@JsonCreator` method should be `public static`